# How to bind only one node of the Kendo TreeView

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, treeview, kendo-treeview

I am using Kendo TreeView and Want to bind one of the node with DataSource and rest are the Static fields.
My Code goes as follows:
HTML:

```
<ul id="TreeView">
    <li>Initiate
        <ul id="IntiateTreeView">
            <li>A</li>
            <li>B</li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li>Analyze
         <ul id="AnalyzeTreeView">
              <li>C</li>
              <li>D</li>
          </ul>
     </li>
     <li class="Analysis">Analysis</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$("#TreeView").kendoTreeView();
```

Now I want to Pupulate the Analysis Node with the Remote Data
So for that I am trying something like as follows:

```
$(".Analysis").data("kendoTreeView").dataSource.data(result);
```

But Not able to do this.

Thanks in Advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1. Create static data on server and pass it to datasource.
2. Append static data to datasource on client side using dataSource.add({});